# Relation between inputs and outputs

Tags: multiple-regression, multilabel

I have a problem which I do not know even if it is theoretically possible (not a ML expert):
Assuming that there is a vector of drugs dosages that people take. So the input vector is something like (0.2, .5, 0.4 ...). The output vector should be the of the same length, suggesting better dosages. Is there a machine learning algorithm that can be used for such a problem?

Edit:
There are many input vectors of drug therapy from people that are using same drugs with different dosages and I can tell if the treatment is succefull (it is not binary but it can be).
The output should be a vector with the best dosages where a value of 0 is accepatble. It will be great if I can add gender and age as inputs.

Comment: This information is not enough. Do you have a vector of drug therapy outcome, for example, so that you can tell which dosage led to which outcome?

Comment: 10XS! Added more info.

Comment: nmnir, as it was noted there are vast possibilities. If your outcome value is not binary but a continuous or categotical value, you can start with printing scatter plot x ~ y, and trying to estimate a degree of relationship between the two. Take correlation measure, for example.

Comment: This is not an answer. You should post this sort of thing as a comment.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyBurnakov at least now I know that it is possible :) Will be grateful for good tutorials.

Comment: Sure, you are welcome. If you prefer MS Excel, start here: http://www.real-statistics.com/correlation/ I personally love this dude for his gentle and deep explanations. I work with R mostly, so I recommend to read something like this: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-test-between-two-variables-in-r

Answer (score 1):

Many machine learning tasks attempt to discover the relationship between two vectors, `X` and `Y` from data containing paired examples of each. In your case you seem to be saying the `X` is a vector of current doses and `Y` is a vector of better doses if you happen to be on `X` already. So you need to ask yourself some questions:

Do I have a reliable set of data pairing examples of current doses to recommended better ones?
Is it reasonable to assume that the second set of doses are dependent to some extent on the first? Perhaps something like "If drug a is at 0.2 and b is at 0.4, then a can be increased to 0.3".

If you answer yes to those questions, you may find ML can help. You sound like you are at the beginning of your learning journey in this field, so find some help or do some reading before you embark on the project in earnest. ML is not a magic solution machine. You need to know what you are doing.

Comment: 10XS. I have read about it and found this http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html about Multiclass and multilabel algorithms. Please see my edit. I didn't find any algorithm that optimize the input vector.

Comment: Based on your edit, I can see that you have two tasks to perform. The first is to build a classifier that maps a drug dosage vector, gender and age to the outcome (whether treatment is successful or not). Once you have that, you then have an optimisation task where you use the model to search for a set of input values that cause the output class to become 'treatment successful'. This might be a simple hill climb, or something more complex like a GA.